# Switch thumbnail image size on hover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am working with MyBB so I am limited slightly.

I basically have a marketplace that lists a small 120x120 image next to each ad. I want it so when they hover the image it expands to a bigger image. My script automatically recreates thumbnails in various sizes and I am trying to use 320x240.

I have tried doing the simple

```
.image {
    height:320px;
    width:240px;
}
```

But have realized that it just stretches the image.

So I am not trying to figure a new way to get my thumbnail to change. Also my thumbnail can **ONLY** be accessed via a PHP variable called

```
{$GLOBALS['threadfields']['key']['thumbs']['160x120']['url']}
```

And this will not display anything except the url to the image, but it is missing the domain name. So for example if I were to echo that variable I would get

```
attach.php?f3fasdfsdfthumb=160x120
```

but to display it I would need to concatenate it to my domain name so it is

```
www.domain.com/attach.php?f3fasdfsdfthumb=160x120
```

I am really lost on how to do this. Basically I just need the image displayed (which is a 120x120 thumbnail, to be swapped with a bigger thumbnail.

I have edited my template to have this at the beginning.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var src = "http://www.worldeducationtips.com/<?php echo $GLOBALS['threadfields']['mimage']['thumbs']['320x240']['url']; ?>";

$('.productimage').hover(function(){
                $(this).attr('src') = src;
             });
</script>
```

My img src class is called productimage.

Answer (score 0):

as it seems to me, your problem can be resolved if somehow the domain name is available to you...

in PHP, you can try using

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

to get the domain name. Once you get it, concatenate it with the string and display accordingly

**EDIT:**Since you have tagged jquery, you can do something like this:

get the `php` variable in a `javascript` variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var src = "<?php echo $php_imgSrc; ?>";
</script>
```

then use it in your hover.

```
$('.image').hover(function(){
                    $(this).attr('src') = src;
                 });
```

Comment: No I think I can figure the domain url. I am just not sure how I can get it to swap thumbnails on hover.

Comment: What if I did var src = "mydomain.com/<?php echo $variable ?>"; Would that work? Thanks for this i will try this nonetheless

Comment: The $ causes a conflict with protocol. Do I just change all the $ to jQuery?